# Turn on monetization on YouTube video via API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I can't find any recent answers on this problem. Does anyone know how to programmatically turn on monetization on a specific video using the official Youtube Data API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this through the API it must be done manually through YouTube studio website